# How Do I Specify A Property Editor for a Custom Activity in Windows Workflow?

Tags: c#, .net, workflow-foundation-4, workflow-foundation

I'm building a list of custom activities and want to specify the editor used when the ellipsis button is clicked. Specifically, I'd like to utilize the key/value property grid type editor for a collection property of my custom activity.

From my understanding I can do this with the EditorAttribute. Is there a list of standard editors that I can pick from?

**EDIT:**

I've tried:

```
[Editor(typeof(System.ComponentModel.Design.CollectionEditor), typeof(System.Drawing.Design.UITypeEditor))]
public InArgument<string[]> Roles { get; set; }
```

and

```
[Editor(typeof(System.ComponentModel.Design.CollectionEditor), typeof(System.Drawing.Design.UITypeEditor))]
public Collection<string> Roles { get; set; }
```

The first method gives me the standard expression editor when clicking on the ellipsis and the second does give me a property grid row with no real editable functionality.

Comment: Check out the docs on UITypeEditor and then look at the classes that are derived from it.

Comment: @MikeCheel, I can use this with the EditorAttribute?

Comment: Read the Remarks section in the docs: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.editorattribute(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the docs at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.editorattribute(v=vs.110).aspx:

> When editing the property, a visual designer should create a new
>   instance of the specified editor through a dialog box or drop-down
>   window.
>
> Use the EditorBaseTypeName property to find this editor's base type.
>   **The only available base type is UITypeEditor.**
>
> Use the EditorTypeName property to get the name of the type of editor
>   associated with this attribute.

**More info:**
My experience with using UITypeEditor has been in customizing the tfs build process however it shouldn't work much different for you (I am guessing). The way I create my custom dialog is to create a class that inherits from UITypeEditor and also override EditValue and GetEditStyle.

```
public class Editor : UITypeEditor
    {
        public override object EditValue(System.ComponentModel.ITypeDescriptorContext context, IServiceProvider provider, object value)
        {               
            if (provider != null)
            {
                IWindowsFormsEditorService service = (IWindowsFormsEditorService)provider.GetService(typeof(IWindowsFormsEditorService));

                if (service != null)
                {
                    using (MyEditorUIDialog dialog = new MyEditorUIDialog ())
                    {
                        DialogResult result = dialog.ShowDialog();
                        if (result == DialogResult.OK)
                            value = dialog.MyReturnValue;
                    }               
                }
            }       

            return value;
        }

        public override UITypeEditorEditStyle GetEditStyle(System.ComponentModel.ITypeDescriptorContext context)
        {
            return UITypeEditorEditStyle.Modal;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I've found this page during my searches but was unable to get any different results. Please see my edit to the question as to how I attempted to use the EditorAttribute

Comment: Alright. I was wondering if there was any editors that I could re-use. I've been able to extend DialogPropertyValueEditor and use it in the same manner. However, I got stuck at trying to get the ExpressionEditor for variable assignment to work in my grid.

Comment: I guess I cannot reuse any editor that I've seen when using other workflow activities. I've been trying to build my own but ran into an issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22361758/custom-parameter-editor-windows-workflow-with-datagrid-having-issues

Comment: Your other stack post doesn't show anything inheriting from UITypeEditor